# svelte typescript component require at least one prop

Tags: typescript, svelte

I would like to create a svelte component that requires at least on prop to be passed to it.

let's say I have a component with two exported props, `a` and `b`:

```
export let a: number | undefined;
export let b: number | undefined;
```

Passing just `a` or `b` should both be allowed:

```
<Component a={1} />
<Component b={1} />
```

But passing none should not:

```
<Component />
```

The overall type would be something like this:

```
type Component = {
    a: number
} | {
    b: number
}
```

But I dont know how to tell svelte this type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this

```js
type PropsA = {
  a: number;
  b?: never
}

type PropsB = {
  a?: never;
  b: number
}

type Props = PropsA | PropsB

const A: Props = {
  a: 1,
}

const B: Props = {
  b: 1,
}
```

Comment: That does not solve the core issue of communicating that to the component interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to specify the property types via `$$Props` but this tries to reconcile the types with those specified on the exports which can lead to errors. The specifics depend on the TS configuration.

E.g.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    type $$Props =
        { a: number, b?: never } |
        { b: number, a?: never }

    export let a: number | undefined
    export let b: number | undefined
</script>
```

Maybe you can make that work for your scenario.

[RFC for this feature](https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/pull/38) (maybe leave some feedback [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/442))